# Install GIT on freeBSD (freeNAS jail) package not found

Tags: git, installation, freebsd, package-managers

I have a freeNas in the office. And  thought to instal Stash git manager (web GUI) there. I created custom jail and got it to see outside world.

Now I am in SSH and i run `pkg install git` and it say

```
root@git:/ # pkg install git                                                    
Updating repository catalogue                                                   
The following 12 packages will be installed:                                    

        Installing p5-GSSAPI: 0.28                                              
        Installing p5-Digest-HMAC: 1.03                                         
        Installing p5-Net-SSLeay: 1.63                                          
        Installing p5-Socket: 2.014                                             
        Installing p5-IO-Socket-IP: 0.29                                        
        Installing p5-Error: 0.17022                                            
        Installing cvsps: 2.1_1                                                 
        Installing p5-MIME-Base64: 3.14                                         
        Installing p5-Authen-SASL: 2.16                                         
        Installing p5-IO-Socket-SSL: 1.992                                      
        Installing p5-Net-SMTP-SSL: 1.01_2                                      
        Installing git: 2.0.0                                                   

The installation will require 181 MB more space                                 

3 MB to be downloaded                                                           

Proceed with installing packages [y/N]: y                                       
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:64/latest/All/p5-GSSAPI-0.28.txz: Not 
Found
```

The problem it cannot find package `p5-GSSAPI-0.28.txz`. I was searching all over the google but most probably since I do not know the nature or the problem, I do not know what to search for and do not know what keywords to search.

I am sure I have to add some custom package repository or something.

how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [p5-GSSAPI](http://www.freshports.org/security/p5-GSSAPI) package is now at version 0.28_1.

The current git package is [git-2.4.6](http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:9:x86:64/latest/All/git-2.4.6.txz). According to the [freshports listing](http://www.freshports.org/devel/git/) it doesn't require p5-GSSAPI anymore.

Maybe your repository configuration is out of date?
Try updating `pkg` first, then run `pkg update`.

After that, I suggest you try again.

**Edit:** It occurred to me that maybe FreeNAS doesn't use the FreeBSD repository. Check the contents of `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/`. On my system there is one file, `FreeBSD.conf`:

```
# file: /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf
# $Date: 2014-02-05 19:48:00 +0100 $
# Repository definition file for the FreeBSD repository.

FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Comment: Try `pkg upgrade pkg`.

Comment: Upgraded successfully. But the same problem after update.

Comment: Try `pkg update` before `pkg install git`. Also check which repo it uses. Maybe FreeNAS doesn't use the FreeBSD repo.